# Order By number as if it is a string in XQuery

Tags: xquery, basex

Using BaseX 8.4.1 which implements XQuery 3.1

I want to order my query result by a certain attribute which contains numbers. Because I need to synchronize this result with a second dataset that stores the corresponding values as strings, I need to sort it as if it were strings, i.e., the values 1,3 and 20 should be sorted like this:

```
1
20
3
```

I tried `order by $x[string(@value)]` and `order by string($x[@value])` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both examples you place part of the expression in a predicate (`[]`), which evaluates to a boolean and returns the expression before the predicate (`$x`), when true.

```
order by $x/@value/string()
```